# How select a object without his childs?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can i select a object without his childs ?
In my code i have :

```
var db = new context();
var result = db.users.include("jobs");
```

Somthing like "not include"

Comment: Maybe something like `db.users`?

Comment: even with db.users a got users with jobs

Comment: Maybe because lazy loading is enabled and it loads the child objects when you want to access them? It won't eager load them unless you explicitly state it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `db.users`, you are actually selecting users *without* related jobs. But if you have lazy-loading enabled, then another database query will be executed when you'll try to access jobs of user. If you don't want another database query to be executed, then just disable lazy-loading. E.g. in constructor of context

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

When lazy-loading is disabled and you will need some related entities without additional queries, then you can *include* them as you do it with jobs now.

Comment: yes in configruation i can do that, but i have many projects working with a same app.config.

Comment: You can adjust app.config for any project. Or use constructor as above

Comment: The problem is, in the confguration of BLL project i have `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;`. and i can't change are configuration  because methods of BLL project colled by many other projects. and many project need LazyLoadingEnabled = true.

Comment: @AddRock so someone uses your dll and enables lazy-loading. It's not clear what level of control you have with this code. What do you have in your assembly? Repositories? Entities?

Comment: I have a method in BLLProject, in this method i got all users `var users = contx.Users` . my question is how can i get all users without childs object ? `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`  is not a good solution for me because this project (BLLProject) is referenced by other projects and if i put `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` to `false`, i got a error in my solution.

Comment: If lazy-loading is enabled and you have virtual navigation property in entity, there is no way you can disable loading related entities. That is how lazy-loading designed in EF. The only option - create another entity which don't have navigation property and return that entity.